# Ошибка NoSuchMethodException в методе main

Tags: java

Появляется ошибка `NoSuchMethodException` при компиляции, в методе `main`. Не могу разобраться в чем проблема, вроде код должен работать. Среда не подсказывает ничего.
В чем проблема?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("main");
        ReadFile readFile = new ReadFile();
    }
}

public class ReadFile {

    ReadFile() {
        System.out.println("readfile");
        Model model = new Model(this);
    }

    public byte[][] getLevel() throws IOException {
        byte[][] r = new byte[10][10];

        try {

            BufferedReader inputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/levels/1.txt"));

            Vector data = new Vector();

            String line;
            int column = 0;


            while ((line = inputStream.readLine()) != null) {

                String[] array = line.split(",");
                byte[] massive = new byte[array.length];

                for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
                    byte element = Byte.parseByte(array[i]);
                    massive[i] = element;
                }
                data.addElement(massive);
                column = massive.length;
            }


            int row = data.size();

            r = new byte[row][column];

            for(int y = 0; y < data.size(); y++) {
                r[y] = (byte[])data.elementAt(y);
            }


            for(int i = 0; i < r.length; i++) {
                for(int j = 0; j < r[i].length; j++) {
                    System.out.print(r[i][j] );
                }
                System.out.println();
            }


        } catch(IOException ioe) {
            System.out.println(ioe.getMessage());
        }
        return r;
    }
}

public class Model {
    ReadFile readFile;
    byte[][] array;

    Model(ReadFile readFile) {
        System.out.println("model");
        this.readFile = readFile;
        try {
            array = readFile.getLevel();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
                System.out.print(array[i][j] );
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Покажите класс ReadFile()

Comment: Не похоже, что ошибка в этом коде. Возможно, она где-то в классе `ReadFile`.

Comment: Покажите полный текст ошибки.

Comment: Добавил остальные классы